# mongoose.connection.readyState causing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readyState')

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongo-memory-server

I've been using Mongo Memory Server for my unit tests and it has been working well but now mongoose.connection is undefined and I'm at a complete loss as to why! I'd expect readyState to at least return 0.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';

let con: mongoose.Connection;
let mongoServer: MongoMemoryServer;

export const connectDB = async () => {
  mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri(), {})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err); // no error is thrown
  });
  con = mongoose.connection; // undefined, but why?!
  console.log(con.readyState); // this line is triggering the error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';

let con: mongoose.Connection;
let mongoServer: MongoMemoryServer;

export const connectDB = async () => {
  mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri(), {})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  con = mongoose.connections[0];
  console.log(con.readyState);
}
```

I resolved the issue by switching mongoose.connection to mongoose.connections[0] as above. I'm not sure if this is an issue with mongoose 7.2.0 or is specific to my workspace configuration.

Comment: Was this an async issue? Rather than resolving the issue have I just found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Using default import `import mongoose from 'mongoose'` when `esModuleInterop: true` or unset  in `tsconfig.json`.

Using namespace import `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'` when `esModuleInterop: false` or unset in `tsconfig.json`.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';

let con: mongoose.Connection;
let mongoServer: MongoMemoryServer;

export const connectDB = async () => {
  mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri(), {})
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  con = mongoose.connection;
  console.log('con.readyState: ', con.readyState);
}

connectDB();
```

Logs:

```bash
 ⚡  npx ts-node ./index.ts
con.readyState:  1
```

package versions:

```json
"mongodb-memory-server": "^8.12.2",
"mongoose": "^7.1.1",
```

Comment: That wasn't the issue but I appreciate your help nonetheless. Thank you!